# Working with EnumSet class in GWT

Tags: gwt

I am having trouble using EnumSet on the client side.

I get this runtime error message:

java.util.EnumSet.EnumSetImpl is not default instantiable (it must
have a zero-argument constructor or no constructors at all)  and has
no custom serializer.

Is this is a known issue?

Here is what I am doing (basically a hello world app)

**Service:**

```
String echo (EnumSet<Names> name) throws IllegalArgumentException;
```

**Client:**

```
echoServ.echo (EnumSet.of(Names.JOHN), new AsyncCallback<String>()
{ ....... });
```

**Shared enum class**
    enum Names { JOHN, NUMAN, OBAMA }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a GWT limitation - See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3028

The simplest workaround is to use a HashSet until that is fixed

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is that `EnumSet` is not serializable according to GWT's rules:

1. It is assignable to IsSerializable or Serializable, either because it directly implements one of these interfaces or because it derives from a superclass that does
2. All non-final, non-transient instance fields are themselves serializable, and
3. As of GWT 1.5, it **must have a default (zero argument) constructor** (with any access modifier) or **no constructor at all**.

See the [docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideSerializableTypes) for more info.